# How do I remove the repeating columns on category page?

Tags: opencart, opencart-3

On the category page, the sub-category are getting repeated in refine search. I have added categories and sub-categories. I have 3 level categories i.e Phone-cases(Parent)->Apple(Sub-category)->iPhone X(Sub-category of apple).

Screenshot:

[image]

```
<?php
{{ header }}
    <div id="product-category" class="container">
        <ul class="breadcrumb">
            {% for breadcrumb in breadcrumbs %}
                <li><a href="{{ breadcrumb.href }}">{{ breadcrumb.text }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        <div class="row">
        {{ column_left }}
            {% if column_left and column_right %}
                {% set class = 'col-sm-6' %}
            {% elseif column_left or column_right %}
                {% set class = 'col-sm-9' %}
            {% else %}
                {% set class = 'col-sm-12' %}
            {% endif %}
            <div id="content" class="{{ class }}">
            {{ content_top }}
            <h2>{{ heading_title }}</h2>
                {% if thumb or description %}
                    <div class="row"> 
                    {% if thumb %}<div class="col-sm-2"><img src="{{ thumb }}" alt="{{ heading_title }}" title="{{ heading_title }}" class="img-thumbnail" /></div>
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if description %}<div class="col-sm-10">{{ description }}</div>
                    {% endif %}</div>
                    <hr>
                {% endif %}
            {% if categories %}
            <h3>{{ text_refine }}</h3>
                {% if categories|length <= 5 %}
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-3">
                            <ul>
                            {% for category in categories %}
                                <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                {% else %}
                <div class="row">
                    {% for category in categories|batch((categories|length / 4)|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
                    <div class="col-sm-3">
                        <ul>
                            {% for child in category %}
                                <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
                <br />
                {% endif %}
            {% endif %}
{% if products %}
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 hidden-xs">
        <div class="btn-group btn-group-sm">
            <button type="button" id="list-view" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_list }}"><i class="fa fa-th-list"></i></button>
            <button type="button" id="grid-view" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_grid }}"><i class="fa fa-th"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group"><a href="{{ compare }}" id="compare-total" class="btn btn-link">{{ text_compare }}</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
        <label class="input-group-addon" for="input-sort">{{ text_sort }}</label>
        <select id="input-sort" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
            {% for sorts in sorts %}
                {% if sorts.value == '%s-%s'|format(sort, order) %}
                    <option value="{{ sorts.href }}" selected="selected">{{ sorts.text }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ sorts.href }}">{{ sorts.text }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6">
    <div class="form-group input-group input-group-sm">
        <label class="input-group-addon" for="input-limit">{{ text_limit }}</label>
        <select id="input-limit" class="form-control" onchange="location = this.value;">
            {% for limits in limits %}
                {% if limits.value == limit %}
                    <option value="{{ limits.href }}" selected="selected">{{ limits.text }}</option>
                {% else %}
                    <option value="{{ limits.href }}">{{ limits.text }}</option>
                {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row"> 
    {% for product in products %}
        <div class="product-layout product-list col-xs-12">
            <div class="product-thumb">
                <div class="image"><a href="{{ product.href }}"><img src="{{ product.thumb }}" alt="{{ product.name }}" title="{{ product.name }}" class="img-responsive" /></a></div>
            <div>
            <div class="caption">
                <h4><a href="{{ product.href }}">{{ product.name }}</a></h4>
                <p>{{ product.description }}</p>
                {% if product.price %}
                    <p class="price"> 
                    {% if not product.special %}
                        {{ product.price }}
                    {% else %} 
                        <span class="price-new">{{ product.special }}</span> 
                        <span class="price-old">{{ product.price }}</span> 
                    {% endif %}
                    {% if product.tax %} 
                        <span class="price-tax">{{ text_tax }} {{ product.tax }}</span> 
                    {% endif %} 
                    </p>
                {% endif %}
                {% if product.rating %}
                    <div class="rating"> 
                    {% for i in 1..5 %}
                        {% if product.rating < i %} 
                            <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span> 
                        {% else %} <span class="fa fa-stack"><i class="fa fa-star fa-stack-2x"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o fa-stack-2x"></i></span>
                        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %} 
</div>
{% endif %} 
</div>
<div class="button-group">
<button type="button" onclick="cart.add('{{ product.product_id }}', '{{ product.minimum }}');"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md">{{ button_cart }}</span></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_wishlist }}" onclick="wishlist.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></button>
<button type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" title="{{ button_compare }}" onclick="compare.add('{{ product.product_id }}');"><i class="fa fa-exchange"></i></button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
{% endfor %} </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-12 text-left">{{ pagination }}</div>
{#  <div class="col-sm-6 text-right">{{ results }}</div> #}
</div>
{% endif %}
{% if not categories and not products %}
    <p>{{ text_empty }}</p>
    <div class="buttons">
        <div class="pull-right"><a href="{{ continue }}" class="btn btn-primary">{{ button_continue }}</a></div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
{{ content_bottom }}</div>
{{ column_right }}</div>
</div>
{{ footer }}
```

Comment: Please add the template code.

Comment: I have edited the question with the code added. Copied from product/category template.@Marco

Comment: You need to work on indentation, I can't easily tell when what if ends where without looking at everything. This is probably what makes it more difficult for you to keep an oversight where things are going wrong semantically. You'll have a lot easier a time checking where an if ends/starts, loops are etc. by doing so.
Busy going through it.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this looks the relevant piece.

```
{% if categories %}
  <h3>{{ text_refine }}</h3>
    {% if categories|length <= 5 %}
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          {% for category in categories %}
            <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    {% else %}
    <div class="row">
      {% for category in categories|batch((categories|length / 4)|round(1, 'ceil')) %}
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          {% for child in category %}
            <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
      {% endfor %}</div>
    <br />
    {% endif %}
  {% endif %}
```

You have the else triggering I think, as you have more than 5 categories.
As you can see, the child in that category gets printed instead of the category that you're trying to trigger. Rather remove the if/else and loop straight through the categories. Each of your children falls under multiple categories as well, therefore duplication.

```
{% if categories %}
  <h3>{{ text_refine }}</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          {% for category in categories %}
            <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Is probably what you want, or if you only want the first category with its children:

```
{% if categories %}
  <h3>{{ text_refine }}</h3>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3">
        <ul>
          {% for child in category %}
            <li><a href="{{ child.href }}">{{ child.name }}</a></li>
          {% endfor %}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
```

Comment: Indented my code in the question. Tried adding you piece of code and after that I cleared the theme cache from dashboard but nothing changed.

Comment: Which one did you copy, may I ask?

Comment: Ya why not. The first one. Please find it below

 {% if categories %}
  <h3>{{ text_refine }}</h3>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
     <ul>
      {% for category in categories %}
       <li><a href="{{ category.href }}">{{ category.name }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
 {% endif %}

Comment: And you're saying there's multiple columns? There is no for loop anymore, so that shouldn't be.

Comment: Ya that's confusing. Even if I make a small change in text that page doesn't reflect. Turned off cache from dashboard too.

Comment: Are you sure that page/template is being called?

Comment: seems you have some extension installed... so you need refresh modifications also.